# Find all rows with value x if there is a pattern of occurence using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Table A

```
--id--something--
|  1 |    x     |
|  2 |    y     |
|  3 |    x     |
|  4 |    z     |
|  5 |    x     |
|  6 |    z     |
```

Table B

```
--id-----A.id-----Value--
|  1 |    1    |   0    |
|  2 |    5    |   1    |
|  3 |   10    |   1    |
|  4 |   17    |   1    |
|  5 |   19    |   0    |
|  6 |   34    |   1    |
```

I want to find all "somethings" from Table A, that have at least one  pattern: there is a row that have a relation to Table B with value = 0 and next row with the same value in column "something" doesn't have relation to Table B at all.

In this case it would be:

```
x
```

because:

Joined Table:

```
  --id--something-- --id-----A.id-----Value--
 |  1 |    x     | |  1 |    1    |   0    |
 |  3 |    x     | |NULL|   NULL  |  NULL  |
```

Comment: your question is not clear can you please share your sample output result set

Comment: This is a complicated request. Why not start with something simpler?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, while certainly do-able, this is quite a complicated request. Anyway, here's something to get you started...

```
 SELECT x.*
      , MIN(y.id) next_id 
   FROM a x 
   JOIN a y 
     ON y.id > x.id 
    AND y.something = x.something 
  GROUP 
     BY x.id;
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | something | next_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | x         |       3 |
|  3 | x         |       5 |
|  4 | z         |       6 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```